# How can I bind an additional property to a DropdownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the following code, the Id of the selected Country is correctly passed back to the controller when the form is submitted. However, I'd also like to pass along the Name of the Country. How can I send the Name along with the Id back to the Controller?

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public List<Country> CountryList { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country.ID,
        new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "ID", "Name"))
   </div>

}
```

**Controller**

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var service = new Service())
    {
        model.CountryList = service.GetCountries();

        return View(model);
    }
}

public ActionResult Index(MyModel tmpModel)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: As you probably have the data stored somewhere, it would be the best approach to retreive the name again at the server by the provided ID. This would also prevent Users tempering with the name data.

Comment: @Chips_100, that's what I had in mind, but was trying to avoid for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: It would definitely be the better approach, and maybe even the simpler one (better comprehensible one for future readers). As @drneel said, you would need to capture the change event on the client with javascript and store the text value of the selected option in a hidden field (for example) to send it to the server as well.

Comment: @Chips_100, Ok, so use javascript to capture the change and then generate a hidden field somewhere on the form? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Right, remember to give the hidden field a `name` attribute, which should match the name of the parameter of your action, so MVC can map the received value.

Comment: I'm away from my dev machine, but something like this: `<input type="hidden" name="Country.Name" value="countryName" />`